# Set up Live Agent on hybrid (Angular/Ionic) app

Tags: liveagent, angular, hybrid, ionic

I've been reading about implementing Live Agent into Angular/Ionic app and the documentation only provides information for iOS and Android native apps. I also tried standard method we already implemented on the web app with no success.

Is it possible to implement Live Agent in hybrid apps?